# VBA Access date format not working?

Tags: vba

Chaps i am trying to get a date into a MM/DD/YYYY format - my code compiles but still sticks to the default DD/MM/YYYY - hear is the code. Have tried passing in a variable as opposed to Date but again no joy - any suggestions?

```
Dim f As Date
f = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: That is because you have a date variable. Make the variable type `string`

Comment: Add some verbiage to your question. The intent might change the answer. Although @shahkalpesh is correct in suggesting the type is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `Format` function does not format date objects but strings. Your code should work by converting the type of your date into string first:

```
Dim f As Date
f = CStr(f) '<-- conversion into string
f = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

### EDIT

*ok so the issue is when I convert the string to a date it drops the format for the string to a standard dd/mm/yyyy - not the mm/dd/yyyy*

You need to keep in mind **who** is reading your date:

- A human being reads the date with his eyes: in other words, he reads *a string* and from there the need of formatting it into DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY or anything else.
- A machine (your computer or anyone else's) reads *a date object*, which is a specific object inheriting the characteristics of your locale settings. If your computer is setted in "DD/MM/YYYY", don't worry: in the USA they will keep on seeing that date in "MM/DD/YYYY", or however the locale settings are.

In other words, if your object is a `Date` type, you don't really need / you cannot change the format of how your machine reads it. To explain you better, if you embed in your code:

```
myMonth = Month(myDate)
```

this variable will return you the *month* of the variable *no matter what is your locale settings*: if you see the date as 24/01/1990, an American guy will see it as 01/24/1990 and the function above will **anyway** return `1` as month.

If you really need to have the date objects like that in your code, you better change the locale settings of your date: `Control Panel / Time, language and region / Region and language / Short date format --> MM/dd/yyyy`.

If your point is processing an SQL request, you're on the track: you don't need to change format to *date objects*, but only to the *strings* used in the SQL. If you need "mm/DD/yyyy", then simply:

```
myDateStr = Format(CStr(myDate),"mm/DD/yyyy")
mySQL = "SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'date' = " & myDateStr
```

And by doing this, the SQL will be always the same **no matter what is the date setting** of the user running the code.

Comment: ok so the issue is when I convert the string to a date it drops the format for the string to a standard dd/mm/yyyy - not the mm/dd/yyyy that I want try this and see what I meen

Comment: Dim GH As String
Dim f As Date



GH = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

f = CDate(GH)

Debug.Print GH
Debug.Print f

Comment: @Mr_Fish please read my edit above and don't hesitate to ask if I still don't see your point.

Comment: OK - so thanks for the info - very inromative and gen thanks - this issue is I want to use the date within an SQL query - as I understand Access processes SQL query (within VBA code) as a string so the underlying meta data of any date object will be lost? So 01/01/2014 will get a weird result I would assume

Comment: Dim f As Date
Dim M_onth As String
Dim D_ay As String


f = Date

M_onth = CStr(Month(f))
D_ay = CStr(Day(f))

If Len(M_onth) = 1 Then

M_onth = "0" & Right(M_onth, 1)

End If

If Len(D_ay) = 1 Then

D_ay = "0" & Right(D_ay, 1)

End If


GH = M_onth & "/" & D_ay & "/" & CStr(Year(f))

Comment: horrible ugly code - but Matteo your post about the explicit Day() etc reference helped hugely with this

Comment: @Mr_Fish I edited my answer, you don't even need to use the "Day()", "Month()" and concatenating the strings, just changing the format **after having converted the date to string**. Please consider to accept the answer if it worked ;)