# Convert Date object to String formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD" instead of defaulting to system format

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to convert a Date to a string in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" (In Access VBA). The issue that I am having is that different users on different computers will have different date formats. I first tried the following:

```
dim dateString As String
dateString = Format(Date,"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

However, if the user's computer settings have their date format as "yyyy/mm/dd" (or any other date format), then it will convert to that rather than "yyyy-mm-dd" as desired.

I've tried solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043057/vba-access-date-format-not-working), however, it still reverts back to the user's date format.

Also, as an aside, I'm aware that Access stores dates in a numeric fashion, and I am not attempting to change how the data is stored, I simply want to convert a date object to a string formatted as "yyyy-mm-dd".

Comment: `Format(Date,"yyyy-mm-dd")` and `Format(Date,"yyyy-dd-mm")` both produce the expected output for me (ie. the output matches the provided format string, not my default date format).  Maybe the real problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Where are you using the dateString variable? Why the Excel tag?

Comment: Where do you put `dateString` to be viewed?

Comment: @TimWilliams those both work for me as well. The issue is that in this circumstance I want the format to be "yyyy-mm-dd" and not, for instance, "yyyy/mm/dd". For example, Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd") is producing "yyyy-mm-dd" for me rather than "yyyy/mm/dd".

Comment: @June7 the variable gets passed onto an Adobe PDF form using the Acrobat SDK, but as far as this issue is concerned, dateString is a String. While I'm working through this issue I am using breakpoints and hovering over the variable name to view the string content.

Comment: and at no time in the code do you convert it to a date, or place it in a date field?

Comment: @ScottCraner that is correct - Even just setting a breakpoint and viewing dateString immediately after the line of code gets executed, you can see that it will still take the form of the computer's default format (ie. if your default format is yyyy/mm/dd/ it will format it as that rather than yyyy-mm-dd).

Comment: it only does that for me if `DateString` is declared a `Date` and not a `String`.

Comment: Can you describe the *exact steps* to reproduce this problem?  In the Immediate window I'm getting the "expected" output whatever format string I use.

Comment: Same here, as stated when `Date` it changes, when `String` it stays: https://imgur.com/fWJFOa5

Comment: @ScottCraner: You are mixing it up. Passing a formatted string to a Date variable should never be done, as it forces an implicit cast from text to date out of your control - determined by the locale of Windows.

Comment: @Gustav which is what both I and Tim are trying to pass to the OP.  We are betting that in the OP's real code the variable is declared a date and not a string which is why the OP is experiencing what they are.

Comment: @ScottCraner: OK, that I didn't catch - assumed the posted code to be the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand you want to change just visually, try this

Good Luck

```
Sub MyCustomDisplayDate()
    Dim dateString As String
    Dim dateDate As Date
  
    dateDate = Now
    dateString = Format(dateDate, "yyyy") & "-" & Format(dateDate, "MM") & "-" & Format(dateDate, "dd")
End Sub
```

Comment: This is no different from your initial approach, only slightly more convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method to force literals into a format: Escape these:

```
dateString = Format(Date,"yyyy\-mm\-dd")
```

Note please, that the dash could be any character.

> For example, Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd") is producing "yyyy-mm-dd" for
> me rather than "yyyy/mm/dd"

This is because the slash is not a literal slash but the *placeholder for the date separator* as to your local settings (a dash). Thus, to force slashes:

```
dateString = Format(Date,"yyyy\/mm\/dd")
```