# User Form in Excel VBA Not Taking The Initialized Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am initializing the User Form with Today's date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. But the form still has date as `mm-dd-yyyy` in Excel VBA

```
Private Sub submit_Click()

UserForm1.Hide

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    tbDateBox.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
End Sub
```

The User Form looks like:
[image]

Where I am going wrong, could you please highlight?

Comment: I used a new form and used ONLY the code you provided and it works just fine. It does not show what your screenshot shows, so it's probably getting set somewhere else too. https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6HCp.png And technically, your screenshot does not show `dd-mm-yyyy` unless 15 is a month.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if your textbox is not actually named `tbDateBox`. Make sure that is correct.

Comment: @braX Corrected the Question.

Comment: My comment still stands. You obviously have more code than what you provided in your question, and something else is populating it in addition to the initialize event.

Comment: Did you check the regional settings in Windows @gm-123?

Comment: @Toni It is working as expected after changing the Regional Format to English United Kingdom. But shouldn't it work with the Format as English India as well?

Comment: @gm-123 I tested your code and it works on my computer perfectly, so I don't know what's the problem. Try using `tbDateBox.Value = Format$(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")`.

Comment: @Toni Even I checked on another machine. It's not working on windows machine, with regional format set to English India.

Comment: @gm-123 try on the same machine, create a new excel file. Place a button and a textbox and set the formatted date as the textbox's value. Try it with `$` and without it. If it work, then your problem with with the old file.

Comment: Maybe try Gustav's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376368/convert-date-object-to-string-formatted-as-yyyy-mm-dd-instead-of-defaulting-to/67376686#comment119092824_67376686